How to specify column data type
I have the following code:
import polars as pl
from typing import NamedTuple


class Event(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    description: str


def event_table(num) -> list[Event]:
    events = []
    for i in range(num):
        events.append(Event("name", "description"))
    return events


data = {"events": [1, 2]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data).select(events=pl.col("events").map_elements(event_table))

"""
shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ events                            │
│ ---                               │
│ list[struct[2]]                   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ [{"name","description"}]          │
│ [{"name","description"}, {"name"… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
"""

But if the first list is empty, I get a list[list[str]] instead of the list[struct[2]] that I need:
data = {"events": [0, 1, 2]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data).select(events=pl.col("events").map_elements(event_table))
print(df)

"""
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ events                            │
│ ---                               │
│ list[list[str]]                   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ []                                │
│ [["name", "description"]]         │
│ [["name", "description"], ["name… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
"""

I tried using the return_dtype of the map_elements function like:
data = {"events": [0, 1, 2]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data).select(
    events=pl.col("events").map_elements(
        event_table,
        return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Struct({"name": pl.String, "description": pl.String})),
    )
)

but this failed with:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = pl.DataFrame(data).select(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/dataframe/frame.py", line 8193, in select
    return self.lazy().select(*exprs, **named_exprs).collect(_eager=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py", line 1943, in collect
    return wrap_df(ldf.collect())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
polars.exceptions.SchemaError: expected output type 'List(Struct([Field { name: "name", dtype: String }, Field { name: "description", dtype: String }]))', got 'List(List(String))'; set `return_dtype` to the proper datatype

How can I get this to work? i need the type of this column to be list[struct[2]] event if the first list is empty.

Trying return pl.Series(events, dtype=pl.List(pl.Struct({"name": pl.String, "description": pl.String})))  raises a PanicException - so this looks like a "bug". If you are in control of the function if events: return events seems to run but would give you null instead.

Seems like a bug indeed. It works at initialization. E.g., pl.DataFrame({'events': [[], [["name", "description"]]]}, schema={'events': pl.List(pl.Struct({"name": pl.String, "description": pl.String}))}).

Quick fix right now
Here's a map_batches implementation that should be at least marginally faster.
def event_table(col: pl.Series) -> pl.Series:
    return pl.Series(
        [
            [
                Event("name", "description")._asdict() #note ._asdict()
                for _ in range(num)
                ]
            for num in col
            ]
        )

It uses nested list comprehensions which ought to be a bit faster than appending to a list in an explicit for loop but that is a python optimization not polars.
pl.DataFrame(data).select(events=pl.col("events").map_batches(event_table))
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ events                            │
│ ---                               │
│ list[struct[2]]                   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ []                                │
│ [{"name","description"}]          │
│ [{"name","description"}, {"name"… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘

You actually just need to use _asdict() rather than relying on polars to infer what a NamedTuple ought to be.
Medium to Long term fix
The issue is here specifically that in certain paths, it treats tuples and lists the same and since a NamedTuple is a tuple, that's why it gets returned as a list.
This PR makes it check for the _asdict method and shifts to treating it as a dict/struct.
With this PR you can do
class Event(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    description: str

def event_table(num: int) -> list[Event]:
    return [Event("name", "desc") for _ in range(num)]

data = {"events": [0, 1, 2]}
pl.DataFrame(data).select(
    events=pl.col("events").map_elements(
        event_table,
        return_dtype=pl.List(
            pl.Struct({"name": pl.String, "description": pl.String})
        ),
    )
)
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ events                            │
│ ---                               │
│ list[struct[2]]                   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ []                                │
│ [{"name","desc"}]                 │
│ [{"name","desc"}, {"name","desc"… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘


As outlined in the comments, this seems to a bug in polars. However, I managed to get this to run by using pl.Field in the definition of the pl.Struct dtype and passing a dict instead of the NamedTuple.
def event_table(num) -> list[Event]:
    events = []
    for i in range(num):
        # note the usage of a plain dict here
        events.append({"name": "my_name", "description": "my_desc"})
    return events

data = {"events": [0, 1, 2]}
pl.DataFrame(data).select(
    events=pl.col("events").map_elements(
        event_table,
        return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Struct([pl.Field("name", pl.String), pl.Field("description", pl.String)])),
    )
)

shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ events                            │
│ ---                               │
│ list[struct[2]]                   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ []                                │
│ [{"my_name","my_desc"}]           │
│ [{"my_name","my_desc"}, {"my_nam… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘

Interestingly, in Jupyter running the following cell afterwards no longer raises an error.
data = {"events": [0, 1, 2]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data).select(
    events=pl.col("events").map_elements(
        event_table,
        return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Struct({"name": pl.String, "description": pl.String})),
    )
)


This doesn't work for me. What version of polars are you running? I am using polars==0.20.16.

Also doesn't work for me in 0.20.17. I guess I'll report the bug in github and see what they say.

@DJDuque Interesting... I was on polars=0.20.15. Now, I've tried with 0.20.17, which also works. Can you try with the latest version 0.20.17 as well?

I opened an issue here. Maybe it would be helpful to the maintainers if you reply there with the output of pl.show_versions() and how you got it to work. I don't know.

@DJDuque Thanks for raising the issue on GitHub. I've added the code and versions I was using as a comment to the issue. Please reach out if there is anything else I can provide - happy to help!

@DJDuque As already mentioned my changes also include the usage of a plain dict instead of the Event type. Of course, you could obtain a dict from the Event object. However, if this renders the solution incomplete, I am also happy to delete the answer.
